# Servicemix, spring-integration, ejb3

Tags: spring-integration, ejb-3.1, apache-servicemix

is there anybody who try to call ejb 3 from bundle on servicemi by use of camel route and spring-integration? I have following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJBObject not found by org.springframework.context

Adding javaee-api doesn't help

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the EJB from any Spring bean only if you register that EJB as bean too.
And what is good, Spring provides a hook for such tasks:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myEjb" jndi-name="MY_EJB_JNDI_NAME"/>
```

Comment: I now, but in my task I need to call remote ejb from servicemix bundle.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that. But maybe you can call a Spring bean from there?..